# Python Error SyntaxError: invalid syntax for no particular reason

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a `SyntaxError` for no apparent reason. I know that Python sometimes gives the wrong line of Error. But I also checked the previous lines and i didn't find any wrong line.

````
import math
import numpy

class neuralNetwork:
        def __init__ (self,inputnodes,hiddennodes,outputnodes,learningrate):

            #set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
            self.inodes= inputnodes
            self.hnodes= hiddennodes
            self.onodes= outputnodes

            ```
            self.wih = (numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnodes,- 0.5), 
            (self.hnodes,self.inodes))
            self.who = (numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnodes,- 0.5), 
            (self.hnodes,self.inodes))

            ```
            # learning rate
             elf.lr = learningrate

            pass
        def train():
            pass
        def query():
            pass
````

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-53-3e0b0716fcb1>", line 13
>     self.who = (numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnodes,- 0.5),(self.hnodes,self.inodes))
>        ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a `)` :

```
self.wih = (numpy.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnodes,- 0.5), 
        (self.hnodes,self.inodes)))
```